# Vue proxy setting does not work

Tags: http, webpack, vue.js

I have a Vue project from `@vue/cli` 3.x.

The proxy I defined in `package.json` based on [this article](https://alligator.io/vuejs/using-new-vue-cli-3/#proxy) is not working. The destination server doesn't see the API request.

What am I missing here?

The vue file:

```
<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Prop, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';
import VueResource from 'vue-resource';

Vue.use(VueResource);

@Component
export default class HelloWorld extends Vue {
  @Prop() private msg!: string;

  constructor() {
    super();

    this.$http.post('/api');
  }
}
</script>
```

package.json:

```
  "proxy": {
    "/api": "http://localhost:9000/api"
  },
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The article likely refers to an outdated method of setting up the proxy. The latest version of `@vue/cli` (currently `3.0.0-rc.3`) has a [new method](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#devserver-proxy) of configuring the dev server.

For an equivalent setup of that proxy, create `vue.config.js` (if it doesn't exist already) with the following contents:

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    proxy: {
      '/api': {
        target: 'http://localhost:9000',
        ws: true,
        changeOrigin: true
      }
    }
  }
}
```